# Body tag is not automatically covering the whole page.. Why?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**It's being kinda disturbing to figure out..**

I don't know why my body stopped to cover all the page, is it something related to the grid system I am using?
I could just put a property saying that the min-height is 100vh but..
WHY is it happening?? I mean, is it something predictable?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estudos-grid.css">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
    Esta div tem 4 partes divididas assim: ----3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr---
    <div class="parte1">a</div>
    <div class="parte2">s</div>
    <div class="parte3">f</div>
    <div class="parte4">g</div>
    <div class="parte5">Aqui usei o grid-column-start de 1 e o "end" de 3</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* mostra como se dividem os pedaços de grid em forma de frações */
    grid-template-areas: 'header header header header'
                        'esquerda centro centro direita'
                        'esquerda centro centro direita'
                    ;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 4fr 2fr 1fr;
    
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    grid-column-gap:10px;
}
.parte1{
    grid-area: header;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.parte2{
    grid-area:esquerda;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.parte3{
    grid-area: centro;
    background-color: green;
    color:white;
}
.parte4{
    grid-area:direita;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    color:white;
}
.parte5{ /* o column start fala em qual linha começa, as linhas são as que estão em volta dos grids, vc diz onde ele vai começar e onde vai terminar */
    grid-column-start:1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: -1;
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Are you wondering why the ".container" does not cover the entire screen by default?

Comment: The `body` element has never automatically filled the entire viewport. The `html` element, however, has. It is indeed something predictable.

Comment: `body` tag has default `display: block` and work as the same as any `display: block;`...

Comment: Ohh.. yes, so my question is "Why the container is not covering the entire page by default"

Answer (score 0):

Apply height property of body to 1vh.
body{height:100vh;}

Comment: This is a confusing answer to the question of "**Why** does the body tag not fill the entire container?"

Comment: Ho, I see your problem.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: This meta tag will make your viewport responsive whether your on a mobile device or pc

Comment: But it won't do anything with the size of the `body` tag.

Comment: That didn't help, @Isaac.mm unfortunately

Comment: I am trying to figure out why the "1fr 2fr 3fr" stuff didn't calculate the height based on the total height of the page..